# Why is Visual Studio saying my file doesn't exist when it evidently does? Also, does it matter that it's adding a forward slash?

Tags: c#, filepath

I have verified multiple times that the file exists, and when I copy-and-paste the path to the file from the code into Windows explorer, it works. It takes me to the file. So please help, what is going on? The exception message, for your reference says

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Couryah\products_export.csv

Why is this forward slash in front of it? Is it the culprit? How do I fix it?

```
public void PopulateList()
{
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Couryah\\products_export.csv");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setAll(line.Split(',')[1], line.Split(',')[3], Convert.ToDouble(line.Split(',')[19].Replace("$", "")), line.Split(',')[24]);
        productList.Add(newProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try taking this portion of the line: r("C:\\, removing it, then retyping it, and see if that fixes your problem? Do not copy/cut and then paste it, select it, delete it, then retype it. (I'm sorry but markdown is being stupid and doesn't allow me to format the string as code because of the double backslashes or whatnot). What I'm wondering is if you have a hidden character in there that might be stored in your .cs file, compiled into the code, but not visible in the editor.

Comment: Another way to have a proper file path there is to Shift+Right-Click the file in Explorer and select "Copy as path", and paste that in code. Prefix the file with @ so that backlashes do not have to be escaped, @"the\path\with\backslashes".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried doing exactly what you said how you said to do it, and unfortunately, I get the same error with the inserted forward slash in the exception message as above. Any other suggestions? Also, "Shift+Right-click" just does the same thing as "Right-Click" on my computer, with no option for "Copy as path"

Comment: Next question, does the program being executed have access to that file, can it see that file? If, for instance, it is running as a windows service under the LOCAL_SYSTEM account, it might not have access to or see that file. Can you clarify?

Comment: Next question, have you accidentally gotten OneDrive to remap your user documents folder, and perhaps the Desktop folder? Is it a local folder? Is it cloud-synced?

Comment: Wouldn't the access issue with it running as a Windows service be resolved by simply restarting the computer? And no, I don't use OneDrive, the folder in question is definitely a local folder. Though I could try moving it to a different folder and see what happens

Comment: Update: Relocating the file proved pointless. Still have the forward slash in there too in the exception's path.

Comment: Just to be sure, this is your exact code? this is the exact exception message?

Comment: Yes, and this is the updated error message: ``` System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Users\Daniel\Downloads\products_export.csv" ``` (Sorry if that doesn't properly format)

Comment: Your *exact code* and the path given by your exception doesn't match. Again, can you please post your **exact** code? If there is some strange mapping for locales that makes "Couryah" mean "Download", can you at least tell us why your original exception used "Couryah" in it, where your comment says "Downloads"?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I changed the path in light of the question about having access to the file in its previous location. But the path of the file in the exception and the code still match the location of the file in the file system.

Comment: Do you observe different behavior if you change it to `@"C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Couryah\products_export.csv")`

Comment: As an aside, you might want to `Split` the `line` once instead of 4 times.

Comment: @Crowcoder I just tried both of those solutions, and still to no avail. Still having the same issue.

Comment: In cases such as this, when behavior seems impossible, it is usually a case of some mistake where you are actually running different code. Some variable is mistyped, or code changes aren't being picked up by the compiler or something. Start over in a new project. What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

I would pre-check to make sure the file exists.  Put into a variable just to be sure no false/bogus value with bad forward slash.  Then, check to see if the file exists or not to confirm BEFORE opening.

Next, instead of stream, I just changed to a File.ReadAllLines() which reads each line at a time into an array.

```
public void PopulateList()
{
    var whatFile = "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Couryah\\products_export.csv";
    if ( ! System.IO.File.Exists( whatFile ))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No such file: " + whatFile);
        return;
    }

    foreach( var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines( whatFile ))
    { 
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setAll(line.Split(',')[1], line.Split(',')[3], Convert.ToDouble(line.Split(',')[19].Replace("$", "")), line.Split(',')[24]);
        productList.Add(newProduct);
    }
}
```

Now, this does not necessarily answer why a file does not exist, but here is one thing I specifically ran into and was scratching the heck out of my head.  I had a similar for a client.  I had a file on the desktop that was a csv, but no matter what, had same issue.

What I actually had found is the file "MyFile.csv" was ACTUALLY a "MyFile.csv.txt".  Wondering what the... Ended up going to a DOS command prompt, changed to folder and did a DIR of that folder to see it.

Come to find, Windows likes to default HIDING FILE NAME SUFFIX of common file extensions.  So, even though the desktop had .csv, because the .txt was hidden was causing the not found file.  To confirm, I changed the file manager to NOT HIDE file name suffix.  Sure enough, stripped the .txt and everything worked.

Not saying this is what you have, but sometimes the obvious isn't.

One more note.  I would put a breakpoint in your debugger to stop at the point of checking the file.  Then use your watch window and see what variables are and also check/change as needed to confirm its doing what you thought it should.

**One additional option...

Try using what WINDOWS thinks is your desktop.**

```
var whatFile2 = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Couryah\\products_export.csv")
```

How does THIS "SpecialFolder.Desktop" compare with your C:\users...

Comment: I've tried checking for a hidden suffix, there isn't one. Implementing your above solution, I still get the path being treated as having the forward slash before the start of the path (as seen above in the top of the question under the title); Regardless of whether I use @ to escape the backslashes, or if I use double backslashes, regardless of how I read the lines of the file. It acts as if I'm mistyping the path, and typing a forward slash, but I'm definitely not.

Comment: @user2996871, understood, just trying to offer something out-of-the-norm.

Comment: I know, I appreciate it. Any other suggestions you can thing of, I would love to hear

Comment: @user2996871, last thought, and I have seen similar confusing things on networks that have managed user profiles in other network locations than you might thing.  See context oat end of answer regarding SpecialFolder.Desktop.  Does this give a different folder than you are trying?

Comment: This is the path i get now, verbatim "/data/user/0/com.companyname.Couryah_Demo1/files/Desktop/\Couryah\products_export.csv".

Comment: @user2996871, yup, that was my second suspicion... Your company has managed profile and desktops... Try reading and processing THAT file and see if the IF FILE.EXISTS works now.